# jq: Can I use the name of an argument in the code itself?

Tags: jq

Is there some way to use the name of an argument in the code?

For example, this command:

```
jq -n --arg name value '{($name): $name}'
```

has this output:

```
{
  "value": "value"
}
```

Is it possible to get this output?:

```
{
  "name": "value"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove the `($name):` JQ will use the name as the key fallback:

```sh
$ jq -n --arg name value '{$name}'
{
  "name": "value"
}
$
```

---

From the [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) [**Frequently Asked Questions**](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ):
<sup>[Notable Differences between Versions](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#notable-differences-between-versions)</sup>

> : In which version was the abbreviation `{$x}` for `{"x": $x}` introduced?
>
> Version ***1.5***

---

From the **Object Construction** (`{}`) [documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#TypesandValues):

> The value can be any expression (although you may need to wrap it in parentheses if, for example, it contains colons), which gets applied to the `{}` expression's input (remember, all filters have an input and an output).
>
> ```
> {foo: .bar}
> ```
>
> will produce the JSON object `{"foo": 42}` if given the JSON object `{"bar":42, "baz":43}` as its input. You can use this to select particular fields of an object: if the input is an object with "user", "title", "id", and "content" fields and you just want "user" and "title", you can write
>
> ```
> {user: .user, title: .title}
> ```
>
> **Because that is so common, there's a shortcut syntax for it**:
>
> ```
> {user, title}
> ```

Comment: The quoted documentation, though suggestive, is actually not definitive on this particular point.  The jq FAQ mentions it, and points out that this bit of syntactic sugar was first introduced in jq version 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. You already know the name you want to use, so either hard code it:

```
jq -n --arg name value '{name: $name}'
```

or use a second variable

```
jq -n --arg key name --arg name value '{($key): $name}'
```

(I forgot about [@0stone0's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68002658/1126841); that's probably what you want to use.)