# how to get the output by jq

Tags: json, jq

So I have below sample codes

```
{
  "host1": { "ip": "10.1.2.3" },
  "host2": { "ip": "10.1.2.2" },
  "host3": { "ip": "10.1.18.1" }
  ...
}
```

I need output of 'host1' and 'host3'

```
{
  "host1": { "ip": "10.1.2.3" },
  "host3": { "ip": "10.1.18.1" }
}
```

with command  `|jq .host1`, I can only get one

```
{
  "ip": "10.1.2.3"
}
```

and I lost its key `host1` as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need output of 'host1' and 'host3'

If you can use a *hardcoded* list of `keys`, you can use the following JQ command to get only `host1` and `host3`:

```
{ host1, host3 }
```

```json
{
  "host1": {
    "ip": "10.1.2.3"
  },
  "host3": {
    "ip": "10.1.18.1"
  }
}
```

---

This uses the **Object Construction Shortcut Syntax** as explained in [there documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#TypesandValues) and in this SO question: [jq: Can I use the name of an argument in the code itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68002556/jq-can-i-use-the-name-of-an-argument-in-the-code-itself/68002658#68002658).

---

[JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/03yKgM1Kqn)

Comment: It even works for keys which are not jq identifiers, except such keys would have to be quoted. E.g. `{"a-b"}`

Comment: @Bill - Please don’t forget to accept the answer.